# Custom close dialog menu buttons

Tags: .net, windows, winforms, api, registry

As you are undoubtedly aware any windows form in the topmost area when right clicking on it will bring up the following menu.

```
|  Restore |
|   Move   |
|   Size   |
| Minimize |
| Maximize |
|----------|
|  Close   |
```

Unfortunately I have no idea what this menu is called and could probably google an answer if I did but either way I have seen applications that have added custom functionality of their own in this area. How would that be accomplished?

I am assuming a registry entry somewhere? Lastly is there some way of passing in the name of the calling process when your custom button is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called 'System Menu' and it can be customized. See this [example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/CustomWinFormSysMenu.aspx). Another and maybe easier to understand example here at [Codeguru.com](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_misc/userinterface/article.php/c9327).

In this case I assumed you're using .NET. Can you confirm this?

Comment: Thank you... Yep I would be using .Net